# ui label not printing the value

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, storyboard

Good morning. Why my code doesn't change the value of `UILabel`? When I click the `UIButton` the function has to multiply the Int value of the variable `meters`, filled as text, by 3 and show it in the `UILabel`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var meters: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var answer: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        answer.text = String(calculateNumber(meters: Int(meters.text ?? "") ?? 0));
    }

    func calculateNumber(meters : Int) -> Int {
        let result = meters
        print(result)
        return result;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your code does not compile : you return a UITextField in a function that should return an Int.

Comment: @PtitXav, no the function is declared to return an Int and does so. Note that the argument to the function is named the same as the text field

Comment: Ok, my mistake . I read to fast your question

Answer (score 0):

Check the code, it should work.
Check that meters are connected correctly.
[image]

Comment: post answer a text and not images.

Comment: Of course, the image is to show the result of the debug.